# How many masks can you own?

Tags: payday-2

In the inventory you can only buy 9 masks but there are more than 50 masks available.

Can you have all the masks? Or are you limited to only one page?

Comment: The mask limit has changed to 36 since the update. They cost 800k each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the [2014 Halloween Update](http://www.overkillsoftware.com/halloween/) on Oct 30th, the mask limit has been increased again to 72:

> Well, the last year has seen a veritable explosion of masks, and seeing as Halloween is about dressing up, and it's kind of a tradition by now we've decided to **increase the mask slots from 36 to 72!**

Comment: Mmmm time to craft me some new goodies then!

Answer (score 5):

Now you are able to have 72 masks.

- Each mask slot costs 800,000.

Buying for example 10 mask slots would cost 8 million.